# R script automation keeps getting closed automatically

Tags: r

I have two files `test.bat` and `test.R`. Here are the contents of the files

`test.bat`

```
R CMD BATCH Z:\AdHoc path\to\test.R
```

`test.R`

```
library(tidyverse)
x <- rnorm(1000,0,1)
p <- qplot(x)
ggsave(p, filename = "plot1.jpeg")
```

I have tried running this by double clicking on the `.bat` file and I have tried running this with [taskscheduleR](https://github.com/bnosac/taskscheduleR). The problem is the same in both instances. What happens is the file start to run and a command window opens, but is immediately closed upon opening and the script never runs.

My machine is a windows 10

I am guessing that there is a setting in Windows that is shutting it down, but I don't know where to start looking.

Comment: What happens when you open a command window and run the line `R CMD BATCH Z:\AdHoc path\to\test.R` at the command prompt?

Comment: Does your command run if you run it directly in a command prompt instead of trying to run it through a BAT file? Getting it to run outside of a script is your first step.

Comment: when I run in the command prompt I get `unable to open output file`

Comment: Well,  now you know where to start looking :-)

Comment: It turned out that my files were on a network drive. I had a hard time getting the the path on the network drive. I moved the files to my desktop, changed the path in `test.bat` then everything worked just fine.